# How do I add expenses for only specific users?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication

I have created two models in my app- one for User (_id, email, username, password) and one for Expense (_id, date, detail, amount, category). For the users, I have finished the authentication with jwt.
I want logged-in users to be able to add/remove expenses and not show their expenses to other users but I don't know how I can implement that. I am not asking for code- I would be grateful if you could roughly tell me what I need to do. Thanks!

```
//expense schema
const expenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        date: Date,
        detail: String,
        amount: Number,
        category: String
    }
)
```

```
//controller for adding expenses
const addExpenseController =     (req, res) => {
    const expense = new Expense({
        "date": new Date(),
        "amount": req.body.amount,
        "detail": req.body.detail,
        "category": "expense"
    });
    expense.save();

    res.send('expense added');
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you want expenses to belong to users? You can do that by recording the owner (user) of an expense in some way. Here's the [Mongo Relationships docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/)

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I am checking the docs now.
Thanks @HenryWoody

Comment: use [CASL](https://casl.js.org/v6/en/package/casl-mongoose) and `CASL (pronounced /ˈkæsəl/, like castle) is an isomorphic authorization JavaScript library which restricts what resources a given client is allowed to access. It's designed to be incrementally adoptable and can easily scale between a simple claim based and fully featured subject and attribute based authorization. It makes it easy to manage and share permissions across UI components, API services, and database queries.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a `ref` property in the expense schema pointing at the `User` model (change the value of the `ref` attribute to equal the model name given to the users):

```
const expenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
      ...
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
  }
)
```

Then, on creation, specify the `user` by setting the value of its `_id`.
You can either store it in the session or pass it in the body, depending on your implementation:

```
const addExpenseController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const expense = new Expense({
      date: new Date(),
      amount: req.body.amount,
      detail: req.body.detail,
      category: 'expense',
      user: req.session.user_id, // or req.body.user_id
    });
    await expense.save();

    res.send('expense added');
  } catch (err) {
    res.send('server error');
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!
I passed the user_id from inside the req.body.user_id. Is this different from saying req.locals.user_id?

Comment: @Anshu `req.session.user_id` is used if you store the parameter in the session using some session manager library like `express-session`. If you need or prefer to pass the `user_id` in the body it makes no difference to the logic. Also, use `async await` since `save()` returns a Promise.